# Iterate over string in mybatis

Tags: mybatis

my string parameter is like this: '(1,2,3,4)'

I want to iterate over this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE value IN #{myparameter}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the value into the query verbatim like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE value IN ${myparameter}
```

But note that this does not use prepared statements parameters. It has all the downsides of not using prepared statements, namely: it is not type save, vulnerable to SQL injection, requires escaping etc

You should better convert the string to a list and then generate the query in a type safe manner:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE value IN
<foreach item="item" index="index" collection="myparameter"
         open="(" separator="," close=")">
    #{item}
</foreach>
```

`myparameter` should be a `Collection` of whatever type the `value` column is.